# Component not rendering using react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm using React Router with the Link tag to handle the routing between the pages on my app. Well, when I click on the home page from the landing page the URL changes but the DOM does not show any of the code that I have for the home component Also I'm not getting any errors and the home page is just blank. I have included the code for my Index.js and App.js so you can see. Just a side note I'm using react-router-dom V 5.2.0, and react-redux V 7.2.2.

**Index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root')
);
reportWebVitals();
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, BrowserRouter, Switch, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';



//COMPONENTS IMPORTS 
import LandingPage from './components/LandingPage';
import HomePage from './components/HomePage';




function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path= "/" component = {LandingPage} />
          <Route exact path = "/HomePage" component ={HomePage} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  )
}

export default withRouter (App);
```

**LandingPage**

```
//tools import
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

//css Import
import '../App.css';

//Animation Import
import Anime from 'react-anime';

//Image Imports
import silentCareLogo from '../Images/silentCareLogo.png';

// React-icons//
import {BsArrowRightShort} from "react-icons/bs";


export default class landingPage extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="landingContainer">
                <div className="logoContainer">
                    <Anime className = "animeDiv" opacity = {[0,1]} duration={25000}>
                        <img src={silentCareLogo} className="companyLogo" alt="logo" />
                    </Anime>
                    <Anime className="animeHmeBtnDiv" opacity = {[0,1]} duration={20000} delay={2000}>
                        <Link to="/home" className="landingHomeBtn">home <BsArrowRightShort /> </Link>
                    </Anime>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
```

**HomePage**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

//css Import
import '../App.css';

//Animation Import
import Anime from 'react-anime';

export default class HomePage extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className ="homeContainer">
                    <h1>home page</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: You should only have one `<BrowserRouter>`. In your code you're wrapping your application in `<BrowserRouter>` both in `App.js` and in `index.js`. I don't think that is causing the problem, it seems to be the fact that your path in `LandingPage` is `/home` but the path you set in the `<Route>` is `/HomePage`. Change it to `<Route exact path = "/home" component ={HomePage} />`

Comment: `landingPage`: spell is wrong

Comment: `HomePage` : Spell is wrong, https://github.com/nkhs/reacttest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check you app.js You home page component is in /HomePage
and you are trying to get it in /home

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={LandingPage} />
          <Route exact path='/HomePage' component={HomePage} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And in the Landing page, you are trying to get home page in /home path which does not exist in your app.

```
<Link to="/home" className="landingHomeBtn">home <BsArrowRightShort /> </Link>
```

whereas your component is in " /HomePage "

Solution:
change your path in App.js from /HomePage to /home

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={LandingPage} />
          <Route exact path='/home' component={HomePage} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I feel so silly, you were right I had put to="/home" instead of to="/HomePage".

Comment: Yes, this is a silly mistake, being a developer try to debug the code first and find whats the actual cause of the problem. This will help you learn from you mistakes.